# Estou tentando resolver um exercíco com arrays em java minha dificuldade é imprimir a média de indice par e impar do array

Tags: java

2. Fazer um  programa java fazer o  seguinte:

a)  Preencher o  array  com as alturas de 30  individuos;

b)  Visualizar o array;

c)  Recorrendo  ao  array,  calcular  e imprimir a média de todas as alturas em  indeces pares do array;

d)  Recorrendo  ao  array,  calcular  e imprimir a média de todas as alturas em  indeces impares do array.

e) encontrar  e imprimir o individuo mais alto  e mais baixo.
Tentei fazer assim:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Array02 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nrIndividuos = 6;
    
        int[] alturas = new int[nrIndividuos];
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < nrIndividuos; i++) {
             System.out.println("Introduza a altura do " + (i + 1) + " individuo");
            alturas[i] = s.nextInt();
        } 
        
        int soma = 0;
        double mediaPar = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < nrIndividuos; j++){
            if(alturas[j]%2==0){
                
                soma = soma + alturas[j];
                
                mediaPar = soma/nrIndividuos;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(mediaPar);
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Qual é a sua dúvida?

Answer (score 0):

Para a média dos indices par, é preferível fazeres um ciclo que comece em 0 e ande de 2 em 2. O mesmo é válido para os ímpares ( a começar em 1).

```
int cont = 0;
for(j=0; j < nrIndividuos; j=j+2){
    soma += alturas[j];
    cont++;
}
media = soma / cont
```

O que estás a fazer no teu programa é a média das alturas pares. Ou seja:
Num array [200,150,195], o teu programa soma 200 + 150 e divide por 3, uma vez que estás a avaliar a paridade de array[j] e não de j. No entanto, o objetivo é somar 200 + 195 e dividir por 2

Obs: é possível retirar a variável cont e utilizar divisões inteiras / restos de divisão por 2, mas para simplificar e ficar válido para par e ímpar, achei por bem utilizar.

Comment: Percebido muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int nrIndividuos = 6;

ArrayList<Integer> alturas = new ArrayList<>();

while (nrIndividuos != alturas.size()) {
    System.out.printf("Introduza a altura do %d individuo: ", alturas.size() + 1);
    alturas.add(s.nextInt());
}
s.close();

List<Integer> pares = alturas.stream().filter(value -> value % 2 == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> impares = alturas.stream().filter(value -> value % 2 == 1).collect(Collectors.toList());


System.out.printf("Pares: %s \n", Arrays.toString(pares.toArray()));
System.out.printf("Impares: %s \n", Arrays.toString(impares.toArray()));

Integer totalPares = pares.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);
Integer totalImpares = impares.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);

System.out.printf("Media Par: %f \n", (double) totalPares / nrIndividuos);
System.out.printf("Media Impar: %f \n", (double) totalImpares / nrIndividuos);

System.out.printf("Menor individuo: %s \n", alturas.stream().min(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get());
System.out.printf("Maior individuo: %s \n", alturas.stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get());
```

Um macete legal é usar Streams, elas reduzem o código bastante. Por exemplo criei uma **lista dinâmica** "*ArrayList*".

Também substitui o **for** por um **while**, ambos tem o mesmo efeito nesse caso, mas o while deixa o código mais agradável.

Agora vamos aos macetes, primeiro usando a lista que contem todas as alturas vamos aplicar uma **stream de filter**, separando todos os pares e impares criando uma lista nova para cada um deles.

Usando a lista de pares e impares vamos aplicar uma **stream de reduce**, o objetivo da reduce é reduzir a lista em apenas um valor, nesse caso vamos reduzir a lista somando todos os elementos, por isso o **Integer::sum**.

Sem muito segredo, o cálculo de média.

Agora vem um outro macete legal das stream, vamos pegar o maior e o menor indivíduo usando as funções **min** e **max**, essas funções elas precisam de um comparador nesse caso vamos usar a **ordem crescente** "ordem natural"

As Streams são funções que trabalham sobre as Arrays / Listas, elas podem ser usadas em cadeia, por exemplo vamos filtrar todos os pares e soma-los:

```
int totalPares = alturas.stream()
                        .filter(value -> value % 2 == 0)
                        .reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```

Espero ter ajudado :-)

Obs: Não esqueça de fechar o scanner quando não estiver mais usando :-)

Comment: Muito obrigado, me ajudou bastante